Write comma separated dataframe as delta format with multiple named columns within pyspark
I have dataframe with single column(details) having 1 Million records , Example of one record mentioned below
30,Ness,42,"SAM,K,Clarke",UK,49,39,denmark,54,7,"SamClarke@gmail.com ,Sam.Clarke@gmail.com",12,25,26,SJ12u,637492,34,"9052, Springfield Road, London EC04 7YP",Europe,London,Male,44,English,8,456774
I required to write this dataframe into delta format in such a way that each comma seperated value treated separate column. Also value present within double quote considered as single column. (example SAM,K,Clarke considered as single column called name).
I have tried with below method but this seems to not working properly .require more efficient way
Create DataFrame with single column
df_single = spark.createDataFrame(data, StringType()).toDF("Details")
Generate the select expression for 29 columns
select_expr = [f"split(Details, ',')[{i}] as col{i+1}" for i in range(29)]
Create new DataFrame with 29columns using selectExpr
df_final = df_single.selectExpr(*select_expr)
any help appreciated here

how are you creating original dataframe?

df[['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3']] = df['details'].str.split(',', expand=True)


This logic not considering "SAM,K,Clarke" as single column , Its get spilt  SAM into separate column and Clarke into other column , Require anything present within double quote considered as single column.

Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

This is what the [DataframeReader.csv()][1] is meant for. You should create your original df using spark.read.csv() instead of reading a single column dataframe and then try to parse each value.
Two options:
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

# create "dataframe with single column(details) having 1 Million record"
orig_df = spark.read.text('path/to/original/data')

# option 1 - just ignore orig_df
# this uses default values https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.5.3/sql-data-sources-csv.html#data-source-option
# sep = ',', quote='"', quoteAll=False
new_df = spark.read.csv('path/to/original/data')
new_df.show()

# option 2
# assuming you don't have access to 'path/to/original/data' and 
# no control over how orig_df is created
orig_df.write.text('some/temp/path')
new_df = spark.read.csv('some/temp/path')
new_df.show()

See csv() docs to understand how you can name the columns / control data types etc. E.g. inferSchema, header options.
